# how to convert a NSArray<NSString*> to std::vector<std::string> and pass it to a c++ function in Obejctive-C?

Tags: c++, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I am new to Objective C and C++, and I have successfully called a C++ function in Objective C following [this tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-c-and-c-in-an-ios-app-with-objective-c/).

However, the example function in the above turorial has no input parameters, it is something like:

```
//In example C++ file:
std::string Greeting::greet() {
    return someString;
}

//In example Objective-C file:
NSString* newTitle = [NSString stringWithCString:greeting.greet().c_str() encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
```

In my case, I have a C++ function like:

```
std::string Greeting::newGreet(std::vector<std::string> s) {
    // do something
    // f(s)
    return someString;
}
```

There is no std::vector<std::string> in Objective-C, so I need to convert a NSArray<NSString*> to std::vector<std::string>.

**How can I make this convertion, and pass it to the `newGreet()` function?**

Comment: There is `std::vector<std::string>` in `Objective-C++`

Answer (score 1):

Depending if you want a vector of strings or a vector of string pointers :

```
std::vector<std::string> vect = {};
for (NSString * str in nsArrayOfStrings) {
   std::string cppStr([str UTF8String]);
   vect.push_back(cppStr);
}
```

Or

```
std::vector<std::string *> vect = {};
for (NSString * str in nsArrayOfStrings) {
   std::string * cppStrPtr = new std::string([str UTF8String]);
   vect.push_back(cppStrPtr);
}
```